# Output of ${PATH#:*} and ${PATH##:*}

Tags: bash, string

The contents of the PATH variable on my system is as follows:

```
> echo $PATH
/c/Users/USER/bin:/mingw32/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/mingw32/bin:/usr/bin:/c/Users/USER/bin:/c/ProgramData/Oracle/Java/javapath:/c/Windows/system32:/c/Windows:/c/Windows/System32/Wbem:/c/Windows/System32/WindowsPowerShell/v1.0:/c/Program Files/Broadcom/Broadcom 802.11 Network Adapter/Driver:/c/Program Files/Toshiba/Bluetooth Toshiba Stack/sys:/c/Program Files/Internet Explorer:/c/Program Files/Common Files/lenovo/easyplussdk/bin:/c/Program Files/Skype/Phone:/cmd:/usr/bin/vendor_perl:/usr/bin/core_perl
```

Now, `${variable## pattern}` deletes the longest matching pattern from the beginning and returns the rest.

Hence, if `arg=${PATH##:*}` should match the longest pattern starting with `:` followed by anything.
`echo $arg` should return `/c/Users/USER/bin`

However, `echo $arg` on my system returns the output as:

```
/c/Users/USER/bin:/mingw32/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/mingw32/bin:/usr/bin:/c/Users/USER/bin:/c/ProgramData/Oracle/Java/javapath:/c/Windows/system32:/c/Windows:/c/Windows/System32/Wbem:/c/Windows/System32/WindowsPowerShell/v1.0:/c/Program Files/Broadcom/Broadcom 802.11 Network Adapter/Driver:/c/Program Files/Toshiba/Bluetooth Toshiba Stack/sys:/c/Program Files/Internet Explorer:/c/Program Files/Common Files/lenovo/easyplussdk/bin:/c/Program Files/Skype/Phone:/cmd:/usr/bin/vendor_perl:/usr/bin/core_perl
```

Similarily, `echo ${PATH#:*}` returns the same output

```
/c/Users/USER/bin:/mingw32/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/mingw32/bin:/usr/bin:/c/Users/USER/bin:/c/ProgramData/Oracle/Java/javapath:/c/Windows/system32:/c/Windows:/c/Windows/System32/Wbem:/c/Windows/System32/WindowsPowerShell/v1.0:/c/Program Files/Broadcom/Broadcom 802.11 Network Adapter/Driver:/c/Program Files/Toshiba/Bluetooth Toshiba Stack/sys:/c/Program Files/Internet Explorer:/c/Program Files/Common Files/lenovo/easyplussdk/bin:/c/Program Files/Skype/Phone:/cmd:/usr/bin/vendor_perl:/usr/bin/core_perl
```

Please help me understand why it's happening this way. Thank you

Comment: You need `${var%%:*}` to remove the suffix and `${var##*:}` to remove the prefix  (greedily, that is)

Comment: yeah, ${var%%:*} seems to be working fine but why wouldn't #{var##:*} work the same way?

Comment: Because `pattern` in `${variable##pattern}` is supposed to match _the beginning of the value of `variable`_... so, in your case, the beginning of PATH does _not_ match `:*`. Read the manual.

Comment: I got it. I got confused earlier. Thank you

Comment: With bash's pattern substitution, `${PATH/:*}` should also expand to `/c/Users/USER/bin`. (It finds the first match `:*`, but isn't locked to the start of the string.)

Answer (score 2):

You have put the `*` glob token in wrong place, put if before `:` as you are using `##` (or `#`) to get rid of the portion from left:

```
${PATH#*:}  ## Non-greedy
${PATH##*:}  ## Greedy
```